# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS even though CORS set up in backend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I have a flask backend and a React frontend. I am trying to do a POST request to my backend but get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is my flask code:

```
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
cors = CORS(app, resource={
    r"/*":{
        "origins": "*"
    }
})

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])

def home():
    df = pd.DataFrame(request.json["challenge"])
    ...
    return pd.DataFrame.to_json(result)

app.run(port=5000)
```

This is my axios request from the frontend:

```
function getPrediction(data) {
  const sending  = {}
  sending['challenge'] = fighters
  axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', sending, {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify `Origin` in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

so the axios request should look something like...

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': ['Origin'],
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict',
    }
    ...
})
```

from the docs https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration-options

allow headers:
`Headers to accept from the client. Headers in the Access-Control-Request-Headers request header (usually part of the preflight OPTIONS request) matching headers in this list will be included in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header.`

allow origin:
`The origin(s) to allow requests from. An origin configured here that matches the value of the Origin header in a preflight OPTIONS request is returned as the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.`

Comment: as a side note, your CORS config is currently using the defaults. so you could simply use `CORS(app)`